# List categories which contain products with specific product attribute

Tags: magento-1.7, product, category, collection, filter

I'm trying to get a list of categories (ID, Name). However, only categories that contain products with a certain product attribute value can be listed.

I've already tried the following;

```
<?php
        $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('product_supplier', '5');

        foreach($categories as $category) {
            echo $category->getName().'<br>';
        }
```

And;

```
<?php
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        $catTree = $category->getTreeModel()->load();
        $catIds = $catTree->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('product_supplier', '5')
        ->getAllIds();
        $cats = array();
        if ($catIds){
            foreach ($catIds as $id){
                $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
                $cat->load($id);
                $cats[$cat->getId()] = $cat->getName();
            }
        }
```

But, I keep getting the error: **Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object**

I found out that this error occurs when the collection tries to filter on the category, so i guess it thinks i i meant to filter by the category attribute product_supplier. I really don't know what to try next.

Suggestions?

**=> My solution so far:**

```
$catIds = array();
$validCategories = array();

//get the filtered product collection
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
   ->addAttributeToFilter('product_supplier', '5');

// Loop through products, throw category id's into array
foreach($productCollection as $product) {
    $catIds = array_merge($catIds,$product->getCategoryIds());
}

/**
 * Loop through category id's, load categories and get name, 
 * create the final array
 */
foreach ($catIds as $x => $catId) {
    $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
    $validCategories[$cat->getId()] = $cat->getName();
}
```

Comment: Can you give a backtrace in which file this call happens as your code doesn't contain any `getBackend()` calls

Comment: It happens in a module i created, in an adminhtml tab. The getBackend, as i mentioned above, gets called when you try to filter a category on a non-existing category-attribute. Alan Storm did a nice article about it here: http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/91985359245/call-to-a-member-function-getbackend-on-a . - That's part of the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tested this, but here is my idea.
You should start from the product collection because you cannot filter a category collection by a product attribute.

```
//get the filtered product collection
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
   ->addAttributeToFilter('product_supplier', '5');

//get a list of all categories
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');

//match products to categories
$productCollection->addCountToCategories($categories);
$validCategories = array();
//check which category has a product count higher than 0
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    if ($category->getProductCount()) {
        $validCategories[$category->getId()] = $category->getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, something like that might work, however, it returns an empty array as for now. It seems the addCountToCategories function doesn't do its job. - I checked if the product i'm testing is active, and was added to active categories, and both are true.

Comment: I made a change. I changed addAttributeToSelect('name') into `addAttributeToSelect('*')`. See if it works like that. I also added for the product collection `addAttributeToSelect('*')` but not sure if that is needed.

Comment: As soon as addCountToCategories adds to the collection, all products disappear. Obviously, but my "special" product doesn't show up either.

Comment: I (temporarily) solved it with my edit in the original post. It's a pretty dirty way tho, especially when the product collection is big.. I really need something cleaner.

Comment: I edited my comment, it's far from a final solution.